# UIPicker from Array of Tuples

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, uipickerview

How can I load a UIPickerView with an array of tuples?

With the following code I only see `Oregon: 9.0` in the UIPickerView.

```
let myArrayTuple: [(String, Double)] = [("Illinois", 7.0), ("Wisconsin", 8.0), ("Oregon" ,9.0)]

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {    
    var stateName:String?
    var stateTax:Double?

    for (name , tax) in myArrayTuple{
         stateName = name
         stateTax = tax
    }
    return stateName! +  ": \(stateTax!)"
}
```

EDIT: Here is how you do it: See answer from `Shadow Of`

In my example below I'm using named tuples instead of the defaults as in `Shadow Of`s example.

```
let myArrayTuple: [(name:String, tax:Double)] = [("Illinois", 7.0), ("Wisconsin", 8.0), ("Oregon" ,9.0)]

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {    

    let stateName = myArrayTuple[row]
    return stateName.name +  ": \(stateName.tax)"
}
```

Comment: You don't use the parameter `row` nor `component`?

Comment: Omg sorry a bit tired. Look at code and you will see that for loop only save last data of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats how you should work with your `UIPickerView`, I guess:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return myArrayTuple.count
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let current = myArrayTuple[row]
    return current.0 + ": \(current.1)"
}
```

Comment: This is for a simple array, mine is an `array of tuples`.

Comment: @fs_tigre This is for declared in your post `[(String, Double)]` array

Comment: @fs_tigre note that you accessing to elements of tuple `current` using default placeholders `0` and `1`

Comment: My bad, this is exactly the way you do it. Also, thank you for pointing out about the placeholders, I ended up naming my tuples  to make it more readable (see my edited question).  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue connected with `for loop` understanding.

```
 for (name , tax) in myArrayTuple{
      stateName = name
      stateTax = tax
 }
```

You go from 0 element till 2 and in each iteration you set new value and do not return it.

And after loop ends you see only last value of the last element in you're case 2.

Comment: I know how for loops works but I'm not sure how to use it to iterate the `array of tuples`. Thanks

Comment: all you need just to return proper item. No problem nice question.